# Hide Location Menubar icon

Tags: menu-bar, siri, macos

I updated my Mac to macOS Sierra yesterday, and now the location icon (which shows that an app is using location services) is almost always present in the menubar. The app using location is `Siri and Dictation` (not using dictation so it's definitely Siri's fault). Short of disabling Siri or blocking it from using my location, how can I get that location icon to get off my menubar?

**Edit:** Now Weather, Calendar, and Siri are all using my location constantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy. Under Location Services, scroll to the bottom of the list and click the Details button next to System Services. In there there's a checkbox for 'Show location icon in menu bar when System Services request your location'

Also: I tried pulling it off the menu bar by Command-Clicking and dragging away. That seemed to make it disappear but I'm not sure if it comes back.

Comment: That checkbox was already off; it seems to me that Siri is not considered a system service.

Comment: Hmm- yeah, I see what you mean... I tried pulling it off the menu bar by Command-Clicking and dragging away. That seemed to make it disappear but I'm not sure if it comes back.

Comment: The issue, uh, went away? I think command clicking and dragging must have helped :D.